# ошибка при создание виртуального девайса в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Подскажите, как исправить такую ошибку:

> ERROR: This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
>   The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0, androidx.core:core:1.1.0, androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0, androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0, androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0, androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.3, androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0, androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0, androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0, androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0, androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0, androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0, androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0, androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0, androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0, androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0, androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0, androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0
>   Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 0):

добавь в файл gradle.properties (в корне проекта, если нет файла - создай) следующее:

android.useAndroidX=true

Comment: прикрепил скрин,посмотрите пожалуйста оно?если оно то не помогло

Comment: нет, файл называется **gradle.properties** а не **gradle-wrapper.properties**

Comment: @avay.r [UPD] такого файла нет, переключите режим списка файлов с **Android** на **Project** https://prnt.sc/s749p8, затем в самом корне создайте **gradle.properties**, в него и впишите нужную строку

Comment: Спасибо помогло)))попросил обновить винду еще, и выдал что нужно поменять настройки в биусе Intel Haxm is required to run this AVD
VT-x is disableid in BIOS
Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings(refer docunentation for yor computer)